# error when submit shipment - Not all of your products are available in the requested quantity

Tags: magento2.3, shipment, stock-availability

Customer created order, and all went well.
Now I try to ship the product and get this error:

```
Not all of your products are available in the requested quantity.
```

I checked and all product are on plenty on stock.
'salable quantity' is also stock minus sold after the order.

Answer (score 1):

Just checked the  product Qty you have in source item table

```
    mysql-> select * from inventory_source_item where sku = %you sku%;
```

Just check the  product Qty you have in legacy Catalog Inventory Stock Item table

```
  mysql-> select * from cataloginventory_stock_item where product_id = %your product id% \
```

If the Qty item is zero in the inventory_source_item update the Quantity item . Then issue will be solved.

Comment: I have checked the product plenty of stock

Comment: There is lots of product which show this error

Answer (score 1):

We were also experiencing this issue when attempting to ship orders.
Even though we had Stores > Configuration > Catalog | Inventory > Stock Options > Decrease Stock When Order Is Placed set to yes.
This meant Magento was decrementing the stock when the order was placed as well as when creating a shipment.
There is a patch here to fix: https://gist.github.com/adamzero1/cef1cc84c80dae7c4fc8c349178bb639
[How To Add/Apply Patches](https://docs.mdoq.io/tutorials/magento-2/creating-and-applying-patches)

Answer (score 0):

to editors: a question can't be properly answered if not enough information is given. if you choose to delete probing questions, maybe nudge the author to provide more information.

@goodlock is this a fresh install or migrated? what version of magento?

i experienced this on a migrated store, magento v2.3.1 from 1.9.4. i assigned products to a source and opened them for editing then cleared cache. i found that some product's data need formatting like removing trailing spaces on SKUs.

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Magento Have integrated Stock reduce when you Shipped. Make sure the Default quantity and Stock Inventory are available to decrease Quantity.

If not resolved then try to indexing.

php -d memory_limit=15G bin/magento indexer:reindex

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by saving that product again.

Hope it helps someones!

Answer (score -1):

You could always try disabling MSI. This is useful if you are using an external stock management system.
https://www.mexbs.com/magento-blog/disabling-the-magento-msi/